# Replace escape character \ from generated JSON string Xamarin.Android

Tags: replace, xamarin.android, json.net, json-serialization

In my Xamarin.Android project, I'm using NewtonSoft Serialization to serialize my Object into JSON string. But when I do this my string has escape characters like this:

```
{\"id\":\"45912345\",\"number\":\"c6474a2345\"}
```

But I want like this:

```
{"id":"45912345","number":"c6474a2345"}
```

I tried to replace the \ character by:

```
var data = "{\"id\":\"45912345\",\"number\":\"c6474a2345\"}";
data = data.Replace(@"\","");
```

but nothing happens. As this is an escape character, this is not printed on console, but I need to send this as form data to my Rest API.

How do I get a valid JSON string?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312974/newtonsoft-json-serializeobject-without-escape-backslashes

Comment: Have you tried to actually sending the data with your rest API without escaping the characters, if so what error are you getting when you do?

Comment: @ismael. Yes, I did, while I send the data with escape character, the API is not able to read the content.

Comment: Could you please add log on your API server side to check what data has the server received?

Comment: @pratiti-systematix What happens when you view it `JSON Visualizer`?