# Remove slash from Json from server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I need to remove slash from my output json. The following function i am using in my API controller. But still i am getting the slash in result. How can i remove this slash?

```
 public string GetEmployeeDetails(string AccessCard)
    {
        DataTable dt =GetEmployeeByAccessCard(AccessCard);
        if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            string JSONresult;
            JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            string outputjson = JSONresult.Replace("\\", "");
            return outputjson;

        }
        else
            return "No Data found";

    }
```

Comment: You can refer to this link and adapt regular expression : https://forums.asp.net/t/1432771.aspx?RegEx+to+remove+double+slashes+from+the+Url+s

Comment: its not working

Comment: @Vahid any specific reason for removing slash from json? What particular functionality are you looking to achieve?

Comment: i created  a web API. I need to get json in proper format as a result of this function. But what i am getting is look like this.

_"{\"ID\":\"3411\",\"AccessCardNo\":\"123569\",\"DP_EmpID\":\"63\",\"EmpOfficialID\":\"EMP020\",\"emp.DP_Degree\":\"710\",\"emp.DP_DepartmentID\":\"699\",\"emp.DP_EmpFname\":\"Feras\",\"ActualDepartureDate\":\"01/01/2099\",\"EmpStatus_HR\":\"Reserved\"}"_

Comment: Is this what the web browser is showing you or are you seeing this in the debugger ?

Check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312974/newtonsoft-json-serializeobject-without-escape-backslashes

Answer (score 0):

In your `json` string two thing is wrong. `Json` starts with `"` and ends with `"` First trim these double quotation. Then replace `\\`. Like

```
string outputjson=JSONresult.Trim('"');
outputjson = JSONresult.Replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public string GetEmployeeDetails(string AccessCard)
    {
        DataTable dt =GetEmployeeByAccessCard(AccessCard);
        if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            string result= Convert.ToString(dt);
            string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Replace("\\", ""));
            return JSONresult;
        }
        else
            return "No Data found";

    }
```