# C# - Remove multiple backslash from JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

In my DB, serialized JSON stored as string and when retrieving and converting JSON and assigning to class object it is throwing deserialization error. Can someone please help me to convert below one.

```
jsonvalue = {{\"Name\":\"\\\"Google\\\"\"}}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (jsonvalue);
```

Need to replace \\\" as \".

When I try, `sb.Replace(@"\\\"",@"\"")` it is showing error `Syntax error , ',' expected`.

Comment: The short answer is what you are doing is likely wrong. What do you think you need to remove the backslashes?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: `sb.Replace(@"\\\", @"\");`  By the way it looks strange for me that you need to replace the backslashes.

Comment: Maybe you should look for improvements when serializing json.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312974/newtonsoft-json-serializeobject-without-escape-backslashes it may help you.