# Backslash appears when I converted it with JsonConvert.SerializedObject

Tags: c#, json

```
List<myClass>() myList= new List<myClass>();
myList.add(new myClass(){ ID=2,Name="2" });
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
```

output :

```
[{\"ID\":2,\"FullName\":\"2\"}]
```

How can I prevent backslash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newtonsoft.Json SerializeObject without escape backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312974/newtonsoft-json-serializeobject-without-escape-backslashes)

Answer (score 0):

In C# when convert an object to json string, it is just a string. In VS studio double quotes must be escaped. So the result you received is correct. Other wise compiler will not be able to compile that string.

When you debug this you can see the string as you want in text preview.