# DataTable to JSON string for amcharts

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, amcharts

I have a method in my model that queries my SQL Server database and stores the results in a datatable. Then, I am using the following method to convert that datatable into a JSON string.

```
public void ConvertDataTabletoJSONString(DataTable dt)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    JSONstring =  serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult getMonthlyData()
    {
        TDR_Monthly viewModel = new TDR_Monthly();
        viewModel.getList(0);
        return Json(viewModel.JSONstring, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My view's javascript AmCharts.makechart dataLoader has this:

```
        "dataLoader":
        {
            "url": "../TDR_MonthlyController/getMonthlyData",
            "format": "json"
        }
```

When I "test" the output of that string (by displaying the string's contents in my view, it shows properly in the browser, like so:

```
 [{"REGION":"Atlanta", "STATE_NAME":"Alabama", "STATE":"AL", "CATEGORY_ID":"0 ", "CATEGORY":"No Group", "COUNT":100, "DEFICIENCY1":0, "DEFICIENCY2":0, "RESCIND1":0, "RESCIND2":0}]
```

However, when I modify the browser's URL to execute the JSON call (http://localhost:49777/Monthly/getMonthlyData) and I open the JSON file, it looks like it has a crap tone of extra spacing and characters:

```
"[{\"REGION\":\"Atlanta             \",\"STATE_NAME\":\"Alabama                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \",\"STATE\":\"AL\",\"CATEGORY_ID\":\"0        \",\"CATEGORY\":\"No Group                                               \",\"COUNT\":100,\"DEFICIENCY1\":0,\"DEFICIENCY2\":0,\"RESCIND1\":0,\"RESCIND2\":0}]
```

The view itself informs me that it cannot parse it

```
Error parsing JSON file: ../TDR_MonthlyController/getMonthlyData
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Are those columns `char` or `varchar`?

Comment: Are you double serializing your string? Perhaps the answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833900/return-json-but-it-includes-backward-slashes-which-i-dont-want) might help.

Comment: @Anderson Pimentel My columns consist of varchars and ints.

Comment: xorspark it would seem that this might be the issue, but now I don't know how to convert my datatable to the proper JSON format for parsing.

Comment: Try `return Content(viewModel.JSONstring...` instead of `return Json(viewModel.JSONstring...` as you already have a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getMontlhyData`, try changing

```
return Json(viewModel.JSONstring);
```

to

```
return Content(viewModel.JSONstring, "application/json");
```

because you already have a JSON string. The `Json()` method is serializing it again.

Comment: Oh man, that was perfect! Thanks!!! The JSON file looks the way it should be, now I Just have to figure out why amcharts is still displaying that it cannot parse the file though =/ do you think its because returning Content does not create an actual JSON file??

Comment: Maybe it's lacking the content type. Check the updated answer.

Comment: yep, that makes the JSON file, but amcharts is still complaining about not being able to parse. I'm going to send a message to their support center and post the solution, should I find one. Thanks so much for your help.