# JSON String parsed and showing back slashes

Tags: jquery, json, model-view-controller

I have been doing some research on how to serialize a datatable to json string. The below code works and is displaying in my API but with back slashes. I have done some research and know that the slashes are happening because I am serializing the data twice. What I dont know is how to fix this issue. I am using MVC and calling the api via jquery.

Here is code that creates JSON String:

```
 _sql = "EXEC [dbo].[GetInvoiceAllTotals] @DateRange = '" + dateRange + "', @AcctGuid = '" + userAccountID.AccountGUID + "'";
        _table = Functions.DataTable(_sql);

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> lst = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> item;
        foreach (DataRow row in _table.Rows)
        {
            item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in _table.Columns)
            {
                item.Add(col.ColumnName, (Convert.IsDBNull(row[col]) ? null : row[col]));
            }
            lst.Add(item);
        }

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
```

Here are the results:

```
"[{\"NoInvoices\":2,\"InvoiceTotals\":null,\"NoPayments\":0,\"PaymentTotals\":null}]"
```

I would like the results to return like this:

[
  {
    "NoInvoices": 2,
    "InvoiceTotals": null,
    "NoPayments": 0,
    "PaymentTotals": null
  }
]

I call the API with the below code

```
            $.ajax({
                 url:"/api/InvoiceTotal/?dateRange=" + $('#dateFilterBy').val(),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (data) {
                      //handle the json response
                     console.log(data);
                },

            });
```

Comment: _"with double back slashes"_ - I don't see any.

Comment: Where do you JSON.parse the string?

Comment: I added the code where i call the API

Comment: @SteveWolfe Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833900/return-json-but-it-includes-backward-slashes-which-i-dont-want or if not is duplicate maybe can solve your issue.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not you call JSON.parse()...

Comment: @Bonfire I do not call JSON.Parse() where should i call JSON.parse()?

Comment: Perhaps do this:

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(data));

Comment: @Bonfire jQuery already does this because of `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: by using JSON.Parse I was able to get the values. Here is what i used var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(obj[0,0].NoInvoices);

Comment: If you have to parse it twice your backend does something wrong.

Comment: I agree, but unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thats why I opened this question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new API call that has fixed the issue.

```
        //Load dataTable from dateFilter
     $("#dateFilterBy").change(function () {
         listInvoices($('#dateFilterBy').val())

         $.ajax({
              url: 'Controllers/Invoices/',
              data: { dateRange: $('#dateFilterBy').val() }
           })
     });

    public ActionResult Index(string dateRange)
    {
        //var searchRange = dateRange;
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userAccountID = _context.AccountProfile.Single(c => c.UserId == userId);
        var invoices = _context.InvoiceMaster.Where(c => c.AccountGUID == userAccountID.AccountGUID);
        List<InvoiceMaster> myInvoiceList = invoices.ToList();


        return View(invoices);
    }
```